# caterpillar identification on fennel

Tags: identification, caterpillar

Location: north Italy (alps)

Yesterday while watering the plants in my garden I noticed a caterpillar on my fennel leaves, and it seemes to eat them. The caterpillar is about 4cm long.
[image]

What kind of caterpillar is this, and will it do any harm to the fennel or any other plant in my garden?  I have leeks, blackberries, mint and lemon balm nearby. Should I do something about it?

It's the first year I ever plant fennel in my garden. I think I planted them on a too shady place, as they are growing over 1m high like a stem instead of growing a "bulb" at the base, so I'm not too worried if the leaves are eaten by the caterpillar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s a caterpillar of a [*Papilio machaon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papilio_machaon), the European swallowtail.

As it feeds on your fennel, it can technically be be seen as a pest, but considering that it won’t eat enough to actually damage the fennel and that it’s classified a threatened species in some regions, I would encourage you to just leave it alone. Its favorite food sources are [*apiaceae*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apiaceae), so from a gardener‘s perspective fennel, carrots, parsnips and dill - which also means that seeing it in a garden is comparatively rare, as the selection of apiaceae is way larger in the wild. None of the nearby crops you mentioned would tempt it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case I will leave it alone and try not to harm it - i like seeing some butterflies in my garden, which has become rare.